# Play/App Store restrictions for over the AIR React Native updates

Tags: android, react-native

I am exploring React Native to integrate in an existing Android app and primary reason to move to React Native is over the air update system.

We want to build new features in React Native so any changes/patches to these features can be deployed without going through playstore process. I have few questions that I am not able to find a clear answer to.

- **Can I add new functionality in my JS bundle and push it over the air ? Does play store allow that ?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because terms and conditions of app stores are off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Play Store allows adding new functionality as long as this new functionality **does not** drastically change the behavior of the app.

Since is only JavaScript (which doesn’t have to be compiled and installed) we can just send out a new JavaScript bundle, and once the user downloads it they have the updated logic.

Have a look at [CodePush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/). Cheers!